# How to dual boot Ubuntu/Win7 without password?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, passwords, multi-boot, wubi

I have Win 7 ultimate on my C drive with a primary partition of 50GB.  There is currently 14GB free.  Is it possible to install Ubuntu  side-by-side with existing win 7 on the same drive without creating a new partition?

When I tried to install Ubuntu by using wubi.exe it takes me the screen asking me to enter password.  I am unable to proceed further since I do not know which password I have to use. I have not set any password for my earlier win 7 ultimate installation.

My computer boots without asking for any password and now I get an error message as Passwords do not match.

Is it possible to install without setting a password?  If yes, will installing Ubuntu have any effect on the Win 7 OS?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the installer for Windows here: [WUBI installer for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

Check the attached image for the Wubi screen. the password and username here are meant for your Ubuntu installation, not Windows. Even 5 GB is enough for a basic installation of Ubuntu, however, you will need more as you install software packages and user files under the Ubuntu drive.

Ubuntu definitely supports installation without a password, however, being a linux environment you will be in trouble soon when you perform administrative tasks. Check here: [Ubuntu without password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114349/when-i-create-an-account-without-password-ubuntu-still-asks-for-it)
Even if you enable the password for Ubuntu account, Ubuntu offers you an option to automatically login at startup. So it is highly recommended to use password for Ubuntu.

[image: Wubi screen]

Comment: I have already seen this screen I want to know which password I have to use since for any password I use it gives error message in red ink that passwords do not match. I am struck at this point.Please advise.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, this is the password you will be using for Ubuntu login. It has nothing to do with Windows password. As it is giving an error saying mismatch, it clearly means you have made a typing mistake and the password entered in both boxes is NOT same. Please retry with same password in both text boxes and you will get through.